# How to check value of INPUT element on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an INPUT element of the TEXT type and I want to perform an action whenever the INPUT's value does not equal a default value. How do I do this? I've looking into jQuery's "change" event handler, but it only works for SELECT elements. Anyhow, here is what I want to do..

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value=\"Default..\" />

$('input[name=test]').FireWhenValueIsChangedThroughTyping() {
 if (value!='Default..') { DoStuffHere(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [keydown function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keydown#fn):

```
$('input[name=test]').keydown(function() {
 if (value!='Default..') { DoStuffHere(); }
});
```

You probably want to bind to `change` as well (which does work for text inputs - it fires on blur) - someone could paste using the mouse, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [blur](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur#fn) event for that. It gets triggered when the user moves away from the input. If you need triggers as the user types, then use the [keypress](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress#fn) event. (See the Examples tab on the linked pages.)

Answer (score 0):

A solution as $.fn:

```
$.fn.FireWhenValueIsChangedThroughTyping = function(defaultvalue){
 $(this).keydown(function(){
  if(this.value != defaultvalue){
    //DoStuffHere
  }
 });
};
```